# How do I convert json.net property is contiguous?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
dataModel = [{"ASB_Base_1":0,"ASB_Idx_1":0,"ASB_Name_Idx_1":"non","ASB_Base_2":0,"ASB_Idx_2":0,"ASB_Name_Idx_2":"non","ASB_Base_3":0,"ASB_Idx_3":0,"ASB_Name_Idx_3":"non"},
        {"ASB_Base_1":0,"ASB_Idx_1":0,"ASB_Name_Idx_1":"non","ASB_Base_2":0,"ASB_Idx_2":0,"ASB_Name_Idx_2":"non","ASB_Base_3":0,"ASB_Idx_3":0,"ASB_Name_Idx_3":"non"},
        {"ASB_Base_1":0,"ASB_Idx_1":0,"ASB_Name_Idx_1":"non","ASB_Base_2":0,"ASB_Idx_2":0,"ASB_Name_Idx_2":"non","ASB_Base_3":0,"ASB_Idx_3":0,"ASB_Name_Idx_3":"non"}]
```

The above data in the model.The format is different from the name of the key looks.

```
public class dataModel
    {
        public int ASB_Base;
        public int ASB_Idx;
        public int ASB_Name_Idx;
    }

    void LoadJsonData(string jsonData)
    {
      List<dataModel> dataModelList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dataModel>>(jsonData);
    }
```

I want to bring in the form of a list, what should I do? Please Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class should be defined like this:

```
public class dataModel
{
    public int ASB_Base_1 { get; set; }
    public int ASB_Idx_1 { get; set; }
    public string ASB_Name_Idx_1 { get; set; }
    public int ASB_Base_2 { get; set; }
    public int ASB_Idx_2 { get; set; }
    public string ASB_Name_Idx_2 { get; set; }
    public int ASB_Base_3 { get; set; }
    public int ASB_Idx_3 { get; set; }
    public string ASB_Name_Idx_3 { get; set; }
}
```